# Modal resizes dynamically, but other divs don't move with it

Tags: css, resize, autoresize

I am not sure if I worded the title correctly.

I have a fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/DdPvu/4/embedded/result/)...

When the content inside the `<div>` forces it to resize, the "I have read this message" button doesn't move with it. I have the height on the `<div>` set to `auto`, so I'm not sure what else there would be...

**Here's the CSS for the modal window...**

```
.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100px; 
    left: 43%;
    margin-left: -360px;
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    background: #eee url(../images/modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 10px 60px 34px 180px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: No, I simply want it to move with the window. This is the way it should look, but unfortunately, I had to change the window's height to accommodate and I want the window's height to resize automatically, or I'm stuck individually sizing every window. Here's another example of how I want it to look. Click [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/EhKXq/3/embedded/result/)

Comment: Was I halucinating just now? @Bala just posted an answer that worked and now it's gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove top:275px; and add bottom: 0px; instead in close-reveal model

And add this div

```
   <div style="position: relative;">
   <a class="close-reveal-modal"></a>
   </div>
```

Comment: I didn't need that `<div>`, although it did work. I simply removed the `top: 275px;` and that was enough. Here's the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/DdPvu/5/embedded/result/).